# Why am I getting a compilation error when overloading the insertion operator <<?

Tags: c++, class, stream, operator-overloading, operators

I am new to C++ (coming from Python and C) so operator overloading is completely new to me.

I have been trying to overload the << operator to be able to represent a string version of a vector class I'm writing, but I keep on getting a (lengthy) build FAILED error, starting with: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:".

These are the parts of my code involved in the issue:

```
//
// Created by mario on 10/03/2022.
//

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class vector3D {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    explicit vector3D(double xPos = 0, double yPos = 0, double zPos = 0) : x(xPos), y(yPos), z(zPos) {}
    std::string to_str() const {
        std::string x_str = std::to_string(x);
        std::string y_str = std::to_string(y);
        std::string z_str = std::to_string(z);
        return x_str + "i + " + y_str + "j + " + z_str + "k";
    }
    double mag() {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
};

vector3D operator*(vector3D A, vector3D B) {
    return vector3D(A.x*B.x, A.y*B.y, A.z*B.z);
}

int operator==(vector3D a, vector3D b) {
    return (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z) ? 1 : 0;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const vector3D &vec) {
    out << vec.to_str();
    return out;
}

int main() {

    vector3D vec1(4, 3, 1);
    vector3D vec2(3, 3, 2);

    printf("%lf %s\n", vec1.mag(), (vec1*vec2).to_str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

I managed to successfully overload the * and == operators, but not <<.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Edit: after a suggestion in the comments that I should include a reproducible example, I have included the entire code, since it's just about 15 lines longer than what I posted earlier.

Note: it seems though I only get the compilation error on mac - very strange.

Comment: Off-topic:  Usually `(x * x)` is more efficient than calling `pow(x,2)`.  The first is a simple multiplication, using a few instructions.  The latter is a function call, requiring instructions to set up the function call and return and functions inside `pow()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ah that makes sense! Thank you for pointing that out, I've already changed my code :)

Comment: You should declare as:  `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const vector3D& vec)`.  The `vec` should be declared as constant since it is not being modified by the function.

Comment: When passing a `vector3d` object, pass by reference or `const` reference if the parameter is not modified.  Otherwise the compiler is going to make a copy of the `vector3d` object, then pass it to the function.  Passing by reference allows the compiler to generate code that accesses the caller's object without making copies.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you very much, but even with this I still get a compilation error :( - even after changing the .to_str() method to const as well

Comment: Reduce the problem set and write code that calls `vector3D::to_string()` directly.  Verify this works before using the overloaded operator.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Is the error during compilation or linking?  Try compiling the above code separately.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you for the suggestion, I have included the entire code as it is quite short

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ah yes it is a linking error! Plus it only happens on my mac, so I haven't the slightest clue what is going on (maybe it's a compiler bug? I'm using CMake)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I also get the same error with gcc (g++) on my mac! I think I'll call it a night for now (2AM here) but thanks again for the help!

Comment: The shown code compiles and links without any errors, whatsoever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it does for me too on Windows, but on mac it keeps on giving me the same error, I have no idea why!

Comment: Perhaps if more detailed information is provided, beyond the "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64", such as what the actual symbol is then maybe, just maybe, the `<<` has nothing to do with it, and the issue is that your Mac compiler is misconfigured in some other, completely unrelated way. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. It should compile on any properly configured C++ compiler, on any operating system.